# e2e testing in Angular: uploading and downloading a file doesn't work using protractor in firefox

Tags: angular, firefox, protractor, e2e-testing

First I should point out that we are running the web app using docker.

I get a prompt when I download a file using protractor in Firefox that prevents me from downloading so I'm trying to disable the download prompt by modifying the `protractor.conf.js` file (code below)

When I try to upload a file using Firefox in headless mode I get an error `Failed: Failed to decode response from marionette` but it works fine if I disable headless mode.

It's required from me to use Firefox and headless mode with this test, I've tried running the tests with chrome and it worked, the issue only happens when using Firefox.
Can someone please provide me with help here?

PS: I've looked into other similar questions but solutions are outdated (angularjs) and they didn't work for me.

Protractor.conf.js

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: 
    // { browserName: 'chrome',
    //   chromeOptions: {
    //     args: ['--headless', "--disable-gpu", '--no-sandbox'],
    //     // prefs: {
    //     //     'download': {
    //     //         prompt_for_download: false,
    //     //         // 'directory_upgrade': true,
    //     //         // 'default_directory': '/home/houssem/Desktop'
    //     //     }
    //     // }
    //   }
    // },
    { browserName: 'firefox',
      marionette: true,
      acceptInsecureCerts: true,
      'moz:firefoxOptions': {
       args: [ "--headless" ],
        prefs: {
          'pdfjs.disabled': true,
          'browser.download.folderList' : 0,
          'browser.download.dir' : process.cwd() + "/Desktop",
          'browser.download.panel.shown': false,
          'browser.download.useDownloadDir': true,
          'browser.download.manager.useWindow': false,
          'browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force': false,
          'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile': true,
          'browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone': false,
          'browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen': false,
          'browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting': false,
          'browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting': false,
          'browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete': false,
          'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk' : 'image/svg+xml,image/vnd.dxf,image/png,image/x-citrix-png,image/x-png', 
        },
      },
    },
  
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
```

app.e2e-spec.ts

```
it('Testing upload button', () => {      
        page.navigateTo('/rules');
        var path = require('path');
        var fileToUpload = '../../tests/rules/rule-regex.json';
        var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
        page.upload(absolutePath);
  });


  it('Testing download button', () => {      
        page.navigateTo('/nodeSymbols');
        page.download();
  });
```

app.po.ts

```
 upload(file){
    element(by.css('.controlPanel .batchUpload')).click();
    element(by.css('#batchUploadInput')).sendKeys(file);
  }

  download(){
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      element(by.css('.controlPanel .download')).click();
      element.all(by.css('#downloadMenu .downloadOption')).get(i).click();
    }
  }
```

Comment: what happens when you remove the firefox option and try ?

Answer (score 0):

```
framework: 'jasmine',

capabilities:     { browserName: 'firefox',
      marionette: true,
      acceptInsecureCerts: true,
      'moz:firefoxOptions': {
       args: [ "--headless" ],
        prefs: {
          'browser.download.folderList': 2, // custom location,
          'browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting':false,
          'browser.download.dir':'/srv/download',
          "browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen": false,
          "browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone": false,
          "browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting": false,
          'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk' : 'application/x-msdownload,application/octet-stream,image/svg+xml,image/vnd.dxf,image/png,image/x-citrix-png,image/x-png,image/jpeg,image/jpg'
        },
      },
    },
```

This works for example try :

```
describe('workspace-project App', function () {
  it('Test Puppeteer screenshot', async function()  {
    await browser.get('https://unsplash.com/photos/gD1t-iP_X4A')
    
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    await  browser.wait(await EC.elementToBeClickable($('[class="_13Q- _27vvN _2iWc-"]')), 5 * 1000, 'Server should start within 5 seconds');

    await $('[class="_13Q- _27vvN _2iWc-"]').click()
    
    await browser.sleep(6000)
  });
});
```